# I am making a quiz app and i want to store 100 question in a .json file but i only want to get 20 randomize questions from it

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a /quiz app and storing 100 questions and answers in a .json file but i only want 20 randomize questions to show.

I am getting an error "List index out of range"

How is this?

This is my code:

```
import random
import json
from tkinter import *
from itertools import zip_longest
import functools

percent = 0
level = 1
level_name = 0
glasses = 0
qno = 0
correctanswer_list = ['Well done!', 'Keep it up!', 'Cool!','Right!']
wronganswer_list = ['Wrong!', 'Better luck \nnext time!', 'Incorrect!']
question_number = [
            "QUESTION NO. 1",
            "QUESTION NO. 2",
            "QUESTION NO. 3",
            "QUESTION NO. 4",
            "QUESTION NO. 5",
            "QUESTION NO. 6",
            "QUESTION NO. 7",
            "QUESTION NO. 8",
            "QUESTION NO. 9",
            "QUESTION NO. 10",
            "QUESTION NO. 11",
            "QUESTION NO. 12",
            "QUESTION NO. 13",
            "QUESTION NO. 14",
            "QUESTION NO. 15",
            "QUESTION NO. 16",
            "QUESTION NO. 17",
            "QUESTION NO. 18",
            "QUESTION NO. 19",
            "QUESTION NO. 20"]
number_question_list = []

with open('questionanswer.json','r',encoding="utf8") as ques_ans_file:
    ques_ans = json.load(ques_ans_file)

with open('highscore.json','r') as score_file:
    scores = json.load(score_file)

root = Tk()
root.title('MMW Quiz App')
root.geometry('300x500')

def welcome():
    global name
    lbl_name1 = Label(text = 'Mathematics in the \nModern World \nQuiz App',font=("Trebuchet ms", 15))
    lbl_name1.place(x=55,y=75)
    lbl_name2 = Label(text= 'Please enter your name:', font=('Verdana',10))
    lbl_name2.place(x=65,y=250)
    name = StringVar()
    name_entry = Entry(textvariable = name, width=30)
    name_entry.place(x=55,y=280)

def destroy():
    root.destroy()
def clear(root):
    for element in root.winfo_children():
        element.destroy()
def menu():
    clear(root)
    start_btn = Button(text = 'Start',
                       width= 15,
                       height = 1,
                       font=("Trebuchet ms", 10),
                       command = functools.partial(quiz,percent,level,level_name))
    start_btn.place(x=90,y=160)
    btnLeaderboards = Button(
        root,
        text="Leaderboards",
        font=("Trebuchet ms", 10),
        width=15,
        height=1,
        command = records
    )
    btnLeaderboards.place(x=90,y=220)

    btnCredits = Button(
        root,
        text="Credits",
        font=("Trebuchet ms", 10),
        width=15,
        height=1,
        command = credits)
    btnCredits.place(x=90, y=280)
    btnQuit = Button(
        root,
        text="Quit",
        font=("Trebuchet ms", 10),
        width=15,
        height=1
    )
    btnQuit.place(x=90, y=340)
```

I dont know if this is the wrong one

```
def shuff_ques():

    i = 0
    while len(number_question_list) != len(ques_ans[level]):
        number_question_list.append(str(i))
        i += 1

    random.shuffle(number_question_list)

shuff_ques()
prcnt = 100/len(number_question_list)

def quiz(percent,level,level_name):
    clear(root)
    global glasses,que_1

    ques_lbl = Label(text=question_number[0], font = ("Verdana",15))
    ques_lbl.place(x = 80, y = 30)

    correct_lbl1 = Label(text = "Score: " + str(percent),font = ("Verdana",10))
    correct_lbl1.place(x = 230,y=5)

    if len(number_question_list) == 0:
        clear(root)
        que_1 = ''
        if percent > 9:
            if que_1 == 9:
                w_lbl = Label(text = 'Good Job, you finish all the questions. \nYou got ' + str(percent) + '!',
                              font = ("Verdana",20))
                w_lbl.pack(pady=(60,30))
                h_button = Button(text = 'Home',
                                  font = ("Verdana",15),
                                  width = 15,
                                  height = 1,
                                  command= menu)
                h_button.place(x=15, y=450)
                scores.append([name.get(), glasses])
                scores.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
                scores.reverse()
                scores.update()
            else:
                scores.append([name.get(), glasses])
                scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
                scores.reverse()
                scores.update()
                res_lbl = Label(text ='Good Job, you finish all the questions. \nYou only got ' + str(percent) + '!',
                                font = ("Verdana",20))
                res_lbl.pack(pady=(0,40))
                h1_button = Button(text='Home',
                                  font=("Verdana", 15),
                                  width=15,
                                  height=1,
                                  command=menu)
                h1_button.place(x=15, y=450)
    n = 75
    question = ques_ans[level][int(number_question_list[0])][0]


    global qno
    ques_lbl.configure(text=question_number[qno])
    qno += 1

    def split_str(que,n):
        args = [iter(que)] * n
        for s in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=''):
            yield ''.join(s)
            correct_lbl1 = Label(text = 'Score: ' + str(percent),
                                 font=("Verdana", 10))
            correct_lbl1.place(x = 230, y =5)

    que_1 = ' '
    for s in split_str(question, n):
        que_1 += s + '\n'

    question_label = Label(
        text=('\n' + que_1),
        font=("Verdana", 10)
    )
    question_label.pack(pady=(80, 100))

    def yes_no(percent,level):
        global glasses,right_answer
        clear(root)
        if r_var.get() == right_answer:
            glasses += prcnt
            percent += prcnt
            right_answer = Label(text = random.choice(correctanswer_list),
                                 font = ("Verdana", 15))
            right_answer.place(x = 110, y = 100)
            correct_lbl1 = Label(text = 'Score: ' + str(percent),
                                 font = ("Verdana",10))
            correct_lbl1.place(x=230, y =5)
        else:
            wrong_ans = Label(text = random.choice(wronganswer_list),
                              font = ("Verdana",15))
            wrong_ans.place(x = 110, y = 100)
            correct_lbl1 = Label(text='Score: ' + str(percent),
                                 font=("Verdana", 10))
            correct_lbl1.place(x=230, y=5)

        check_button.destroy()
        ques_lbl.destroy()
        option_1.destroy()
        option_2.destroy()
        option_3.destroy()
        option_4.destroy()
        if len(number_question_list) == 0:
            w_lbl = Label(text='Good Job, you finish all the questions. \nYou got ' + str(percent) + '!',
                          font=("Verdana", 20))
            w_lbl.place(x = 80, y = 90)
        else:
            nxt_btn = Button(text = 'Next Question',
                             font = ("Verdana",10),
                             width = 15,
                             height = 1,
                             command = functools.partial(quiz,percent,level,level_name))
            nxt_btn.place(x = 90, y =280)

    choices = ques_ans[level][int(number_question_list[0])][1]
    r_var = IntVar()

    option_1 = Radiobutton(text = choices[0],
                           font = ("Verdana", 10),
                           variable = r_var,
                           value = 0)
    option_1.place(x=30, y=150)
    option_2 = Radiobutton(text=choices[1],
                           font=("Verdana", 10),
                           variable=r_var,
                           value=1)
    option_2.place(x=30, y=180)
    option_3 = Radiobutton(text=choices[2],
                           font=("Verdana", 10),
                           variable=r_var,
                           value=2)
    option_3.place(x=30, y=210)
    option_4 = Radiobutton(text=choices[3],
                           font=("Verdana", 10),
                           variable=r_var,
                           value=3)
    option_4.place(x=30, y=240)
    global right_answer
    right_answer = ques_ans[level][int(number_question_list[0])][2]
    number_question_list.pop(0)

    check_button = Button(text = "Verify",
                          height = 1,
                          width = 15,
                          command = functools.partial(yes_no,percent,level))
    check_button.place(x = 90, y = 450)
    root.mainloop()

def records():
    def delete_score():
        scores.clear()
        menu()
    clear(root)
    record_label = Label(text='Records',
                         font = ("Verdana", 15))
    record_label.pack()

    if len(scores) > 5:
        del scores[5:]
    if len(scores) > 0:
        score = 0
        while score != len(scores):
            score_lbl = Label(text = '\n' + str((score + 1)) + '. ' + (scores[score][0] + ' ' + str(scores[score][1])),
                              font = ("Verdana",10))
            score_lbl.pack()
            score += 1

        clear_score_btn = Button(text = 'Clear Records',
                                 font = ("Verdana",10),
                                 height = 1,
                                 width = 15,
                                 command = functools.partial(delete_score))
        clear_score_btn.place(x = 20,y = 450)
        back_btn = Button(text='Back',
                          font=("Verdana", 10),
                          height=1,
                          width=15,
                          command=menu)
        back_btn.place(x=80, y=450)
def credits():
    clear(root)
    lbltxtCredits = Label(root,
                          text = 'Credits',
                          font = ("Verdana",15))
    lbltxtCredits.pack(pady=10)
    labeltextCredits = Label(root,
                             text='Team 9 \n\nArellano, Jayven\n\nChavez,Ivan Louige\n\nDelos Santos, Thea\n\nMelivo,Angel',
                             font=("Verdana", 15))
    labeltextCredits.pack(pady=10)
    btnBack = Button(root,
                     text="Back",
                     font=("Verdana", 10),
                     height = 3,
                     width = 15,
                     command=menu)
    btnBack.place(x=10, y=430)

enter_btn = Button(text='Enter', width = 10, height = 1, command=menu)
enter_btn.place(x=110,y=330)

welcome()
root.mainloop()
with open('highscore.json','w') as score_file:
    json.dump(scores,score_file)
```

this is my .json file, im still currently adding up 100 questions on it.

```
["Mathematics in the Modern World",
  [["Regular, recurring, and repeating \nforms or designs that are commonly \nobserved in natural objects",
    ["Sequence", "Patterns", "Variables", "Fibonacci Sequence"], 1],
  ["Ordered list of numbers called \nterms; it may have repeated values; the \narrangement of these terms is set by a definite rule",
    ["Variables","Fibonacci Sequence ","Patterns","Sequence"], 3],
  ["Placeholder; quantity that may \nchange within the context mathematically \nor in experiments.",
    ["Fibonacci Sequence", "Variables","Sequence","Patterns"], 1],
  ["Performed by adding the two \npreceding numbers starting from 0 and 1",
    ["Patterns","Fibonacci Sequence","Sequence","Variables"],1],
  ["Well defined collection of \ndistinct objects",
    ["Subset","Set","Proper Subset","Proper Set"],1],
  ["Basic relation of the set is by \nof subset",
    ["Subset","Set","Proper Subset","Proper Set"],0],
  ["Atleast one is a Subset",
    ["Subset","Set","Proper Subset","Proper Set"],2],
  ["All things of the given property \nis true",
    ["Universal Statement","Conditional Statement","Existential Statement","Statement"],0],
  ["If one thing is true, then the \nother also has to be true",
    ["Conditional Statement","Existential Statement","Universal Statement","Statement"],0],
  ["There is at least one thing which \nthe property is true",
    ["Existential Statement","Universal Statement","Conditional Statement","Statement"],0],
  ["\"For all\" and \"If-Then\"",
    ["Existential Universal Statement","Universal Conditional Statement","Universal Existential Statement","Existential Statement"],1],
  ["First part asserts that a certain \nobject exist and is universal, \nbecause the second part says that the first part satisfies a property",
    ["Universal Existential Statement","Existential Universal Statement","Universal Conditional Statement","Existential Statement"],1],
  ["The first part tells that a certain \nproperty is true for all objects",
    ["Universal Conditional Statement","Universal Existential Statement","Existential Universal Statement","Existential Statement"],1],
  ["From specific to general; process \nof reaching a general conclusion by \nexamining specific examples.",
    ["Deductive Reasoning","Inductive Reasoning","Conditional Statement","Existential Statement"],1],
  ["From general to specific; general \nassumptions,procedure and principles",
    ["Deductive Reasoning","Inductive Reasoning","Conditional","Existential"],0],
  ["It is defined as the study of \npatterns, numbers and arithmetic operations.",
    ["Discrete Mathematics","Mathematics","Geometry","Trigonometry"],1],
  ["What is the 20th term of the \nnumber sequence; \n8; 16; 24; 32; …?",
    ["140","150","160","170"],2],
  ["What is the 20th term of the \nsequence of number \n2; 5; 10; 17; 26; 37; …?",
    ["301","401","501","601"],1],
  ["It is an ordered list of \nnumbers, called terms that may have repeated values.",
    ["Pattern","Sequence","Set","Reccurence Design"],1],
  ["It is a regular, repeated, \nor recurring forms or designs.",
    ["Shape","Design","Forms","Pattern"],3],
  ["Considered to be the most \ntalented Western Mathematician of the Middle Ages",
    ["Albert Einstein","Pythagoras","Leonardo Fibonacci","Plato"],2],
  ["The Fibonacci numbers also \nhave a geometric manifestation in the form of:",
    ["Pattern","Sequence","Common Ratio","Golden Ratio"],3],
  ["Which number is next in the \nFibonacci sequence of numbers: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21..",
    ["55","59","34","44"],2],
  ["Which of the following is NOT \nan example of Fibonacci numbers found in nature?",
    ["Pinecone Spiral","Number of petails in daisy","A mountain range","Spiral on the sunflower"],2],
  ["What is one way to decide if \ntwo numbers follow a Fibonacci sequence?",
    ["If their sum is as the same as their difference","If their ratio is approximately the golden ratio","If each number is an odd number","If the product is a prime number"],1],
  ["Correct arrangement of \nmathematical symbols",
    ["Simpler expression","Expression","Mathematical expression","Simple Mathematical"],2],
  ["Which is not a Characteristics \nof mathematics?",
    ["Precise","Range","Concise","Powerful"],1],
  ["The product of ten and y",
    ["10 + y","10y","y|10","y-10"],1],
  ["Twenty decreased by a number t",
    ["t - 20","20 - t","20 + t","-(20 - t)"],1],
  ["Four times the sum of twelve and y",
    ["12y + 4","4(12 + y)","(12 + y) - 4","4(12 - y)"],1]]
]
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about when (and where -- it should tell you the line in the file) the error occurs?

Comment: line 156, in quiz
    ques_lbl.configure(text=question_number[qno])
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `qno` keeps incrementing past the length of the `question_number` array.

You need to do something like this:

```
global qno
if qno < len(question_number):
    ques_lbl.configure(text=question_number[qno])
    qno += 1
else:
    # show notification that the quiz is over
    # e.g. message box with the final score
    qno = 0
    menu()
    return
```

BTW, I loved your quiz (not that I did particularly well on it, but the questions were interesting)

Comment: i tried it but after question number 20, it goes back to question number 1

Comment: what did you do exactly after the `else:`? you need to show notification that the quiz is over and probably return to the menu page or just quit the app...

Comment: i tried this : 
else: 
clear(root)
menu()
but the questions are not removed, it overlay the menu buttons

Comment: You need to return from the `quiz` function. I've updated my answer to add more details.

Comment: it works! thankyou so much